# How can I create a mailing list for internal discussion in my firm

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, mailing-lists, public-folders

How can I create a mailing list for internal discussion in my firm?
Like we have the SAS mailing list, can we have a SAS mailing list for my SAS discussions inside my firm itself?

Comment: Not with only an email client...

Comment: Are you using Outlook? Which version?  Do you want to Set Up a Distribution List?

Comment: We have outlook 2010, and I was thinking a Distribution list might suffice. The issue is how to look into archived discussions?

Comment: I recently got some info about public folders acting as internal bulletin boards. Anybody tried that?

Answer (score 1):

Run your own mailing list software - [mailman](http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/index.html) is an option i see used a lot, and has web based archives but [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/72940/alternatives-to-mailman) has other options you may want to look at.

Comment: Hey Thanks- but now I a looking at the problem from a different perspective- I was thinking of using the public folders as internal bulletin board.

Comment: @AmulDotPdf - What do you mean using the public folders as a internal bulletin board?  It sounds like this is a new question.

Comment: My intention was to have a common place where people can ask questions about say SAS/Excel within organization(and it could be a long term documentation). Hence I thought of the mailing list. Even better could be to use public folders in outlook as a bulletin board having threads- may be that could be a replacement for the mailing list/distribution list. The answers contributed here are sufficient though.

Comment: In which case you may want to select the best (better?) answer as correct so the question won't be periodically bounced as not having a correct answe

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com) (or other service that offers lists and groups - [listserv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LISTSERV)) - you will get an address such as:
internaldiscussions@googlegroups.com

Invite all that you want to include in the group.

All correspondance will be with that address.

Comment: Hey thanks- but I was looking at some way in which I would not have to give data to some outside vendor.